# Calling stored procedure on Inherited class in [Fluent] NHibernate without discriminators

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a working Fluent project with some inherited tables

```
class Base { int BaseId }
class Derived : Base {}
class Derived2 : Base {}

class BaseMap : ClassMap<Base> { ID BaseId ); }
class DerivedMap : SubclassMap<Derived> { Id( BaseId ); }
class DerivedMap2 : SubclassMap<Derived2> {Id( BaseId ); }
```

These tables do not have a dedicated "discriminator" column, NHibernate just figures it out.

I've noticed that the SQL queries it runs, even if I specifically request a `Base` entity, it will join to all subclasses, add a `CASE` statement with a parameter named `clazz`, and use that to return a proxy with the extended objects available (so *it* knows if there is a 'derived2' in existence and will just give me that). This all works fine...

**Problem**

I have an existing stored procedure that returns records from `Base`. I'm trying to call this via `CreateSqlQuery` like so:

```
Session.CreateSQLQuery( "exec SP_GetAllFromBase" )
       .AddEntity( nameof( Base ) )
       .List<Base>();
```

But when I try to map it an entity type of `Base`, I get an `IndexOutOfRange` exception as NHibernate tries to find a `clazz` property in the returned result set (just like it adds onto all its own queries...). But the stored procedure is just returning rows from `Base` and not adding a special case statement to the end.

Is there is way I can tell `CreateSqlQuery` that it *specifically* needs to return a `Base` instance and not `Derived`?

Comment: Have you tried `Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec SP_GetAllFromBase").SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Base>()).List<Base>();` ?

Comment: iirc this doesnt work either as transforming to base still does the "actually transform to a derived class" thing

Comment: have you tried it? resulttransformer does not take into account the mapping at all.